# Where is the collapse edges option in 2.70?

Tags: sculpting

I can't find the collapse edges button for dynamic topology sculpting in the new 2.70 blender update. Where is it?

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic topology behavior was updated in [this commit](https://developer.blender.org/rB19089092739c):

> This allows you to choose between subdivide edges, collapse and both. Being able to
>   only collapse edges can be useful to simplify meshes with accidentally introducing
>   more detail.

The *collapse short edges* option was renamed to *collapse edges*.

[image]

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: no, it should say collapse short edges, but thanks for your help!!

Comment: @cameron I think it was renamed to collapse edges.

Comment: nvr mind, it was subdivide collapse :)

Comment: @cameron Did that solve your problem then?